# Handle orientation in iOS6 with Mono

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, ios6

I have same issue found on XCode for this question

[Unable to handle orientation in iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519693/unable-to-handle-orientation-in-ios-6)

I haven't found on Mono mapped method

```
this.windows.setRootViewController(viewControllerObj);
```

How Mono fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set it in your AppDelegate's FinishedLaunching method:

```cs
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    [...]
    window.RootViewController = viewControllerObj;
    [...]
}
```